# how to find value if it appears in next 3 consecutive times group by column

Tags: mysql

i have table with 3 columns , now how find value if it appears next 3 times immediately

```
     date               tran_val                name
1    23mar                22                    mark
2    24mar                22                    mark
3    25mar                22                    mark
4    26mar                22                    mark
5    27mar                22                    mark
6    28jan                99                    john
7    29jan                99                    john
8    30jan                99                    john
9    31jan                99                    john
```

output is like

```
   date               tran_val                name
1  23mar                22                    mark   
2  24mar                22                    mark
6  28jan                99                    john
```

i.e 1st trnas_value appears in next 3 consecutive times (repeaded 4 times)
and 2nd and 6th also rows also repeaded the same..
thanks in advance